# Angular-CLI App Specify Uglify settings?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular-cli app running and building fine, however I'm bumping into this issue with aot and uglify:  [git-hub issue](https://github.com/linemanjs/lineman-angular/issues/8) / [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018142/angular-currency-filter-symbol-%C3%82-added)

In the past to mitigate it I customized the rollup.config.js file with the following:

```
 plugins: [
        ...
       , uglify({ output: { ascii_only: true } })

    ]
```

How do I specify this custom uglify plugin setting with an angular-cli app?

---

This stems from the fact that we have some view templates using `&nsbp;` in them to add whitespace.  Maybe I need to look at an alternative for that escape sequence instead of ejecting the cli and losing parts of it's magic.

Comment: If you want config beyond what the CLI exposes, `ng eject` the webpack config.

Comment: Does that mean i lose the ability to run the app via ng commands?

Comment: I haven't done it, I don't know, but you can surely roll back the change if it doesn't suit.

Comment: @cobolstinks after an `ng eject`, you will still be able to use the `ng` commands that create code, but the commands to run and build a project move to `npm` scripts, like `npm start` rather than `ng serve`. The output at the command prompt after running ng eject will show what the replacement commands are. You can look in the package.json to see them, too. [This might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861191/how-to-work-with-ngcli-after-ejecting-the-webpack-config/44861648#44861648).